# Testing @ConditionalOnClass autoconfigurations

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

We have developed a number of 'in-house' Spring Boot Starters & autoconfigurations supporting various NFRs such as logging, configuration, security, etc.

The biggest testing challenge we face is how to test different combinations of `@ConditionalOnClass` autoconfigurations.

For example:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(Foo.class)
public class Config1 {

}

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(Bar.class)
public class Config2 {

}

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingClass(Foo.class)
public class Config3 {

}
```

How can we manipulate a test project's classpath to test various combinations of `Foo` & `Bar` jar files being present on the classapth? Are there any libraries out there? I wonder how the Spring guys do this?

Comment: Why would you need to test this and not unit test the underlying functionality/components instead? The `ConditionalOn...` is used everywhere and highly unlikely to break i.e. is it really worth your time to test something that would be done by the framework anyway.

Comment: We have multiple `@ConditionalOnClass`autoconfigurations that behave in subtly different ways depending on different classpath combinations. It's  a glorified `if-else` statement where the Boolean condition being evaluated is the presence / absence of specific jars on your classpath.

Comment: So why not have the client applications test what they expect to be loaded as they will have the correct/expected classpath conditions, like they really should be if this is that critical. Else you are into a world of hurt as you would need something like different maven profiles to exclude/setup the depencies correctly and then test but again why should you do this. Autoconfiguration is great until it isn't, if these autoconfigs are that critical perhaps the configuration should not be auto'd but manually defined via annotations meta-annotations.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Thanks for the tip. I never knew dependencies could be put in profiles! It might be exactly what I need.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is the ApplicationContextRunner.

```
@Test
public void whenDependentClassIsNotPresent_thenBeanMissing() {
    new ApplicationContextRunner().withUserConfiguration(ConditionalOnClassConfiguration.class)
        .withClassLoader(new FilteredClassLoader(DependentClass.class))
        .run(context -> assertThat(context).doesNotHaveBean(BeanConditionalOnDependentClass.class));
}
```

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-runner